# Can you be convicted of a crime when you could not avoid doing so because of a bug in a state-owned mobile app?

Tags: united-states, liability, oregon

Oregon offers electronic licenses and tags for hunting and fishing; the problem is that the app does not work reliably offline, despite advertising this feature. (It's very common to not have an Internet connection when fishing and (especially) hunting.) If the state police ask me to show them my hunting license, but I can't because the state's app won't load, did I do anything illegal?

Paper licenses and tags are available, but you have to pick paper or electronic; "electronic with paper backup" isn't an option.

(**Content warning**: description of hunting)

Showing the license is fairly simple, because a screenshot would likely be okay. The bigger issue is tagging; after catching a fish or killing an animal that requires tagging, you have to enter information about it into the tag. As far as I know, this must be done immediately, and there are no explicit exceptions for the app not working.

Comment: I’d first check if there is a difference between hunting/fishing without a license, and without being able to show an officer the license. And if he arrests you and takes you to the station, your license appears!

Comment: It would be negligible by the officer if he doesn't know these problems. So if you cannot show the license (and it's obviously because you're offline), I would expect that he asks you to show it later somehow.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's very likely a big difference. Forgetting your driving license at home is certainly less problematic than not having one in the first place.

Comment: @gnasher729 there's another scenario where you are expected to do something in the app immediately, but I didn't want to describe it to avoid offending people.

Comment: Please, describe it so we can better understand the root issue.  (Is it tagging?) Any legal requirement that needs immediate internet access in the wilderness is not well thought out…

Comment: @MichaelHall yes, it's tagging. In theory, it does work offline if you keep the app open in the background, but if you accidentally tap "close all" or your phone's battery optimizer decides to top the MyODFW app, you need an Internet connection to recover.

Comment: I'm not really clear on the "force-majeure" tag here.  I recommend that you remove that.  What's to prevent you from taking a screen image of the license and saving that in the device's local storage.  Then you would be able to show it on demand.  You could also do the old-fashioned thing and print out a copy that you could show.

Comment: @jwh20 a screenshot should work for the licenses but you have to enter information into the tag.

Comment: They do offer paper licenses and tags as an alternative, and I use them. You can't use the app but have a paper backup, though.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that tag; I removed it.

Comment: You could help people get started on answering this question by doing some of the background research and including it in the question.  For instance, can you find the section in state law or regulations that requires tagging? The section that allows you to do this via the phone app?  The section that makes it a crime to do so?  (One important point about the latter is what level of intent or *mens rea* the crime requires.)